# ffmpeg specific jpeg encoding

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg

I'd like to convert a movie into jpeg in a specific way. I was wondering if ffmpeg can help here.

What I need to achieve is every 25 frames from the movie needs to be written in a single `.jpeg` file - one under another. So that from a single movie I get

```
part1.jpg
  frame1
  frame2
  frame3
  ...
  frame25

part2.jpg
  frame26
  frame27
  frame28
  ...
  frame50

...
```

Can this be done without dumping the file into separate `.jpeg`s and then modifying them?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a jpeg of every 25th frame (i.e., ignoring every other frame), starting at frame 1? Or are you looking for some kind of composition of 25 frames into one image?

Comment: A composition of every 25 frames into one `partXXX.jpeg` - frames saved one vertical stripe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm far from an ffmpeg expert, but I don't believe ffmpeg is capable of this level of image processing by itself.  I think, in order to achieve your desired goal, you'll need this workflow:

1. Extract all frames to individual, temporary image files with *ffmpeg*;
2. Combine a sequence of 25 temporary image files into a single final image with a JPEG tool (such as *montage* from the ImageMagick package);
3. Repeat step 2 until all final images have been created.

This should be fairly easy to script, but it will take up a lot of disk space while it's working.

Comment: Exactly - I wanted to save on the disk space by not creating every frame separately...

Comment: some other tool might be able to do that, but i don't think ffmpeg is capable, sorry.  (i could also be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

With a recent ffmpeg, you can simply use the [tile](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) filter like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v 'tile=layout=1x25' out%03d.jpg
```

This will produce files labelled out001.jpg, out002.jpg, and so on; and each image will be exactly as described in the question.